# Digitizing 2-node lines?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I tried digitizing in to a new sqlite line layer with autoincrement id ticked.....

- I want to create a 2-node line, but there seems to be a minimum limit of 3 nodes. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? (left click to add a node, right click to complete the line)
- once I right click the attribute dialog pops up no no auto incremented id.... I actually just want to digitize the lines with *no* further attribute data to be added and the id autoincremented. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 1):

In 2.8, digitizing a 2-node line is left-left-right click. (Right click ends it without adding another node.)

Try this and report back if the auto increment id is still an issue.